# PC will try to wake up immediately upon entering sleep mode, becomes stuck

Tags: windows-10, boot, sleep

I am consistently observing the following weird behavior:

When I put my PC to sleep it does what you would expect: stop monitors, lower fan RPM, turn off the LEDs etc. That is while it's entering sleep mode. The moment it's **in** sleep mode, the power button immediately lights up and so do the lights in the case. The monitors remain off, the mouse and keyboard can't wake up the PC. All the fans are spinning at max speed and are noisy. I also notice a red LED with a label "CPU" on the motherboard. The power button is completely unresponsive, can't shut the PC down.

But the weirdest thing is that if I quickly restart the PSU from the switch next to the power chord, the PC will boot up as if it had woken up (e.g. programs I left open would still be open and in the same state).

This started happening like a week ago, I have no idea what caused it.

I am completely dumbfounded and out of ideas. I tried all of the things a simple google search of the issue turns up and none of them worked.

Here's my build:

PSU: EVGA - 850 B5, 80+ BRONZE, 850W

MOBO: Gigabyte B550 Aorus Pro

RAM: Kingston Fury Beast 16GB(2X8GB) DDR4 PC4-25600

GPU: ASRock AMD Radeon RX 6600 XT Phantom Gaming D 8GB OC

OS: Windows 10

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**EDIT**

Tested hibernate, it also wakes up immediately but is not stuck like sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

After much testing and research, I narrowed down the issue to a UPS connected to a USB3 port which kept waking the PC up. Apparently it was incompatible with USB3 and moving the connection to USB2 fixed sleep mode.